# Binding multiple buttons to a event handler

Tags: c#, event-handling, commandargument

I don't have any experience on events & delegates. Been trying to do something from what I found on SO and other sources over internet for past few days.

What I'm trying to do is a custom OnPageChange event for our custom pagination. After I (hopefully) did that, I'm told to do three more things;

1 - An "onclick event" inside our control

2- Making all linkbuttons to call this onclick event

3- Raising OnPageChange event from buttonclick of linkbuttons.

So far I did these;

Inside our custom pagination control (name is PagingControl)

```
public class PageChangeEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    private int PageNum;

    public PageChangeEventArgs(int PageNum)
    {
        this.PageNum = PageNum;
    }

    public int Page
    {
        get
        {
            return PageNum;
        }
    }
}

public class ClickEventArgs : EventArgs
{


    public ClickEventArgs()
    {

    }
}

public delegate void PageChangeHandler(object sender, PageChangeEventArgs e);

public delegate void PageChangeClickHandler(object sender, ClickEventArgs e);

//------------------------------------------------------------------------

public partial class PagingControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public event PageChangeHandler PageChange;
    protected virtual void OnPageChange(PageChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        PageChange(this, e);
    }


    public event PageChangeClickHandler PageChangeClick;
    protected virtual void OnPageChangeClick(ClickEventArgs e)
    {
        PageChangeClick(this, e);
    }

        //------------------------------------------------------------------------

.
.
.
}
```

Also, I'm trying to let the OnPageChange know which page it is by sending command arguments from buttons. An exampe;

```
btnNext.Text = String.Format("<a href=\"{0}\"><b>{1}</b></a>&nbsp;",
                GetPagingUrl(Convert.ToString(this.CurrentPageId + 1)), "<img src='../../img/next.gif' border='0' />");
            btnNext.CommandArgument = Convert.ToString(this.CurrentPageId + 1);
```

These are all so new and alien to me, I'm lost at how will I get the buttons and the eventhandler talk.

I mainly used this page among many others to get things done: http://www.windowsdevcenter.com/pub/a/dotnet/2002/04/15/events.html